# send value from noUIslider to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, nouislider

I try to send the value from my slider to the saveprofile.php file with query post.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzq7yym3/

and here the code snippet for jquery post:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         var einestundeslider = document.getElementById('slider_einestunde');
        $("#saveprofilebutton").click(function(){
            $.post('saveprofile.php', 'val=' + einestunde.noUiSlider.get(), function (response) {
      alert(response);
   });
});
          });
```

saveprofile.php looks like this:

```
   $value = $_POST['val'];
   echo "I got your value! $value";
```

But i receive nothing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per JS fiddle you are missing '>' in html syntax at the end of this line:    `<div id="slider_einestunde"></div`

So Html code should be like this:

```
<form action="saveprofile.php">
<div id="slider_einestunde"></div>
```

Secondly you are using wrong variable name to get the value, actual value is: 'einestundeslider' but you are using 'einestunde'

Fixed version of your JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/48n4jp33/

Comment: oh feeling really stupid right now, but thank you very much that you helped me. !!! :)